# getNextSibling for next product in product type

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I’m setting up a Craft Commerce website, and at the end of the product pages, I’d like to add a link to the next product in the same product type as the current product.

For regular entries, I used `{{ entry.getNextSibling().url }}` to get the next entry in the current section, but I can’t figure out how to get the same result for the products.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`getNextSibling` works in the context of a Structured Section for [Entries](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getNextSibling) and for [Categories](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/categorymodel#getNextSibling) because both of them have the concept of a *hierarchy*.  i.e. in a Structured Section and a Category Group, each element can have parents and children.

Commerce Products don't have hierarchy natively.  Could be a bit of a pain to maintain, but you could simulate it by adding an "Order" number field to your product field layout and manually enter the order for each product in a product type, grabbing all of them in Twig and doing the sorting there.

Answer (score 0):

Incoming hack!

Ok, So I had to solve this problem just now under a super deadline, and Brad's suggested sort field on a product was not a viable solution for the deadline. Here is how I implemented having a product detail page where a "Next Product" and "Previous Product" link works, based on products that have a Category field with a common selected category.

It works based on the `postDate` of the products that have the common category.

```
{# The product object is the product I'm viewing in this template #}

{# Make sure you have a category element to sort products on first,
   this is how I'm getting mine for this solution: #}

{% set category = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getSegment(2)).first() %}

{# Next, let's take the currently viewed product's 
   post date, subtract a minute, and then get the next previous
   product that lives in the relatedTo sort #}

{% set timeLimit = product.postDate|date_modify('-1 min') %}
{% set prevProduct = craft.commerce.products.relatedTo(category).postDate("<=" ~ timeLimit|date('c')).first() %}

{# Awesome! We have the previous product with the relatedTo category 
   with the closest oldest postDate #}

{% if prevProduct is null %}
    No previous
{% else %}
    <a href="{{ siteUrl }}store/{{ category.slug }}/{{ prevProduct.slug }}">{{ prevProduct.title }}</a>
{% endif %}

{# Now we do the exact opposite to get the next product #}

{% set timeLimit = product.postDate|date_modify('+1 min') %}
{% set nextProduct = craft.commerce.products.relatedTo(category).postDate(">=" ~ timeLimit|date('c')).first() %}

{% if nextProduct is null %}
    No next
{% else %}
    <a href="{{ siteUrl }}store/{{ category.slug }}/{{ nextProduct.slug }}">{{ nextProduct.title }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

For my solution, I will be replacing the "No next" and "No previous" with a link to the oldest `postDate` and newest `postDate` products with these queries, creating a loop.